# How to create same animation as it in square application in ios?

Tags: ios, animation, tableview

AppStore link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/square-one-shopping-centre/id400294134?mt=8

I want to create same animation as it is SQUARE application's first screens tableview.

When tableview scroll is up and down cell comes with animation. Can any one help me to   achieve this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"notificationCell";
    notificationCell *cell = (notificationCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"notificationCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (notificationCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    cell.imgFacebookTwitter.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tw_icon.png"];

    return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to play with `CATransform3D` animations and apply it in 
`willDisplayCell:cellforRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Check out this tutorial - [Animating UITableView Cells](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/animating-uitableview-cells/).

It should point you in the right direction.